# Is it possible to display another column in Entries type field?

Tags: control-panel, entries-field

I would love to be able to show another column inside Entries type field. Specifically, Image field. Basically,the same functionality as on the Entries list. Is there a plugin or another way of implementing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not out of the box – but being able to display fields in addition to the entry title for selected entries being displayed in an Entries field, in an easy-to-use interface like the Customizable Element Index, sounds like [a killer feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues).

For now, your best (albeit not super *easy*, I suspect) bet would be to [create a custom plugin](https://pluginfactory.io) that adds a custom [FieldType](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/field-types) extending the [EntriesFieldType](https://craftcms.com/classreference/fieldtypes/EntriesFieldType) class.

By overriding [the BaseElementFieldType's `$inputTemplate`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/fieldtypes/BaseElementFieldType.php#L52) property (i.e. by adding an `$inputTemplate` property to *your* custom FieldType's class, pointing to a different template) you might be able to display entries in a different manner compared to the vanilla Entries field.